# Cannot write in InputBox inside a frame of a website

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, iframe, web-scraping

this post is the following of [Filling Internet Explorer inputbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483919/vba-filling-internet-explorer-inputbox/27485486#27485486)

We tried to isolate the problem and it seems that I'm not able (maybe due to a JavaScript in the page? - Please take a look to the other post) to correctly address to the specific InputBox I want. The code which I wrote:

```
Sub AddInfoFromIntranet()

Dim Ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set Ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With Ie
        .navigate "[HERE GOES MY WEBSITE]"
        .Visible = True

        Do Until Not .Busy And .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Doc = .document
        Set Elements = Doc.getElementsByName("Nachnamevalue")

        .Quit
    End With

    Set Ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

"Nachnamevalue" is a name of an element contained in the "top_window" frame of the web page:

[image: HTML of the Frame]

The picture above is what I get opening my desired address, pressing F12 and clicking with the "select item" item on the desired inputbox. 
At the very beginning instead the page is just a bunch of javascripts (opening page - F12 and copying the content of DOM explorer)

Now, if I try to see what my "Elements" variable is, I get an object basically empty.

[image: Empty object]

If instead I write:

```
Set Elements = Doc.getElementsByName("top_window")
```

something is to be found.
Unfortunately I'm working on an INTRANET page, so I cannot provide you the address.

EDIT: FULL javascript

```
<html><head><script language="JavaScript">

    function NewWindow(window_name){
        var detail; 
        detail = open(window_name,"detail","dependent,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=400,height=400");
        detail.focus();
    }

    function NewWindowScroll(window_name){
        var detail; 
        detail =    open(window_name,"detail","dependent,scrollbars,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=600,height=500");
        detail.focus();
    }


    function NewWindowSize(window_name,w,h){
        var detail, windata;
        detail = open(window_name,"detail","dependent,scrollbars,resizable,screenX=250,screenY=250,width=" + w + ",height=" + h);
        detail.focus();
    }

    function MiniWindow(window_name){
        var detail; 
        detail = open(window_name,"miniwindow","dependent=no,resizable=yes,screenX=0,screenY=0,width=800,height=20");
        detail.focus();
    }



    last_timer="new"    

    function DoSearch(){
        document.Suchform.submit() 
    }

    function wait_and_search(){ 
        clearTimeout(last_timer)
        last_timer = window.setTimeout("DoSearch()", 400);
    }


    function check_kpeq(this_handle){
        equ_string = this_handle.value;
        text = equ_string.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z\-]/g,"");    
        zahlen = text.split(/[\-\/]/);              
        if (zahlen.length != 4) {falsches_equ_format(this_handle);  return false;}

        fill="000";

        Zahl_1   = fill + zahlen[0];    
        Zahl_1 = Zahl_1.slice(Zahl_1.length-3)

        Zahl_2   = fill + zahlen[1];    
        Zahl_2 = Zahl_2.slice(Zahl_2.length-1)

        Zahl_3   = fill + zahlen[2];    
        Zahl_3 = Zahl_3.slice(Zahl_3.length-2)

        Zahl_4 = zahlen[3];

        this_handle.value = (Zahl_1 + "-" + Zahl_2 + "-" + Zahl_3 + "-" + Zahl_4);

        return true;      
    }


    function check_anab(this_handle){
        anab_string = this_handle.value;
        if (anab_string == "") {return true;} 
        text = anab_string.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g,""); 
        zahlen = text.split(/[\-\/]/);              
        if (zahlen.length != 3) {falsches_anab_format(this_handle);  return false;}

        fill="000";

        Zahl_1   = fill + zahlen[0];
        Zahl_1 = Zahl_1.slice(Zahl_1.length-2)

        Zahl_2   = fill + zahlen[1];    
        Zahl_2 = Zahl_2.slice(Zahl_2.length-2)

        Zahl_3   = fill + zahlen[2];    
        Zahl_3 = Zahl_3.slice(Zahl_3.length-3)


        this_handle.value = (Zahl_1 + "-" + Zahl_2 + "-" + Zahl_3 );

        return true;      
    }


    function falsches_anab_format(this_handle) {
        t1 = "Ung?ltiges Format f?r HVT AN/AB:  >>  " + this_handle.value + "  <<\n\n";
        t2 = "Nur 3 Zahlen mit '-' als Trennzeichen erlaubt\n\n";
        t3 = "Z.B.: '01-08-001'"
        alert(t1 + t2 + t3);
        this_handle.focus();
    }


    function falsches_equ_format(this_handle) {
        t1 = "Ung?ltiges Format f?r EQU:  >>  " + this_handle.value + "  <<\n\n";
        t2 = "Nur 4 Zahlen mit '-' als Trennzeichen erlaubt\n\n";
        t3 = "Z.B.: '003-2-60-7'"
        alert(t1 + t2 + t3);
        this_handle.focus();
    }


    function check_form(){

        if (check_kpeq(document.editanlagedata.KPEQ)        == false){return false};        
        if (check_anab(document.editanlagedata.HVAN)        == false){return false};        
        if (check_anab(document.editanlagedata.HVAB)        == false){return false};        
        return true;
    }

</script>


    <title>Telefon-Suche</title>    
    <link title="Telefonsuche - Abteilung" href="[XML FILE REGARDING WEBPAGE].xml" rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml">
    <link title="Telefonsuche - Name" href="[XML FILE REGARDING WEBPAGE].xml" rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml">
</head>
<!-- frames -->
<frameset rows="90,*" bordercolor="#ffffcc" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="top_window" src="index.cfm?fuseaction=StdSearchForm" scrolling="No">
    <frame name="bottom_window" src="index.cfm?fuseaction=ShowStartpage" scrolling="Auto">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
```

Comment: add javascript code please

Comment: @Noldor130884 please add also a picture of the watcher to the object, as you showed me in chat, to display the content to the other users.

Comment: Which library should I reference to in goal to use SHDocVw and MSHTML objects ?

Comment: "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "HTML Object Library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that when your target input box 'Nachnamevalue' is inside of an `IFrame` then IE has to **navigate to target page first and then to the IFrame as well**.

If no navigation to the `IFrame` occures, then the DOM does not contain elements which are inside of `IFrame` and that is why it was not working. HTH

*(The sample code uses files which are located on my PC, so replace the url with your actual url from intranet and the name of the 'main.html' with the name of actual page.)*

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub AddInfoFromIntranet()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    ' Navigate to main page first
    url = "file:///c:/temp/Noldor/"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url & "main.html"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim inputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrames As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement

    ' Get top_window frame and navigate to it then
    Set doc = ie.document
    Set iFrames = doc.getElementsByName("top_window")

    If Not iFrames Is Nothing Then
        Set iFrame = iFrames(0)
        ie.navigate url & iFrame.src

        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set inputs = doc.getElementsByName("Nachnamevalue")
        If Not inputs Is Nothing Then
            inputs(0).Value = "Test123"
        End If
    End If

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample HTML of `main.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset cols="" rows="">
  <frame name="top_window" src="top_window.html" />
</frameset>
<noframes>
<!-- no frames content here -->
</noframes>
</html>
```

Sample HTML of `top_window.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffcc">
  <form name="Suchform" action="index.cfm">
    Nachname:
    <input name="Nachnamevalue" type="text" size="8">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```