# GetelementsByTagName seems to not work properly

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyname

this question sounds stupid but how come when I use the function GetElementsByTagname("frame") , it only returns 3 as a length and not 5 as I expected ?

Here is the [HTML of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6KTc.png)  where I counted 5 times the apparition of the tagname "frame" but when I ask for the length in VBA I get 3...

My observations :

1) You can see that 3 is the number of main frames (top_navigation, contentframe, dummyframe)

2) If I try to access to one of the mainframes via getelementbyname, it works but if I try to access on the the subframes of contentframe ( leftnavigation or postfachcontent) it doesn't work ( 0 item detected)

Here is my code :

```
Dim Frame As IHTMLElementCollection
  Set Frame = IEDoc.getElementsByName("contentframe") ' this works and returns 1 item
   MsgBox Frame.Length
   Set Frame = IEDoc.getElementsByName("postfachcontent")
  MsgBox Frame.Length ' this returns 0 item


Dim Collection As IHTMLElementCollection

Set Collection = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("frame")
MsgBox Collection.Length ' this returns 3 and I expected 5...
```

Comment: Have you tried using a MSHTML.FramesCollection?  setting from IEDoc.Frames?

Comment: I have never heard about the type MSHTML.FramesCollection. How do I use this ? If I simply change the type of _Collection_ to it, I have a mismatch of course.

Comment: Using IEDoc.Frames?

Comment: I still only get 3 frames in it

Comment: does col(1).frames.length give a result?  You may need to iterate the collection and then check for embedded frames

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506705/cannot-write-in-inputbox-inside-a-frame-of-a-website).

Comment: Oh yeahh this gives me 2 ! Which means it spotted those 2 "sub-frames". That's awesome, thanks man

Comment: @dee : this is exactly what I was looking for ! Awesome ! I will implente it in my code and post the result

Comment: @dee : I went through the link you gave me but by replacing your PC location path by the URL of mywebpage it doesn't seem to work. You used "main.html" but I don't know what's the equivalent of this for a website. You proposed to replace this part by the "name" of the webpage, you meant "title" ? I am a bit confused...Also in my case I will have to change this method a bit since I cannot "navigate" to a new webpage with the new path so I should copy it in an existing internet window instead.

Comment: You have url of the page with frames (so called main page). Then you have a `src` argument of some frame e.g. `/puma/xls/common/framesets/all/allsearchframe.html`. First IE navigates to main page. When main page is loaded then let IE navigate to some frame. To navigate to some frame combine the home-url with the src of frame. When home url ends with file name then take just the part without this file name. Could you post the format of your main Url?

Comment: @dee The problem is that it's an intranet link, but also that it' s a link which is unaccessible directly (even for me). My full code consists of going on an accessible intranet webpage, then providing username+password and once you submit these info a new separate page will open as well. I then activated this page to get to its information. This latter is the so called main page from the sample of code, so basically if I use its url and navigate to it, it doesn't work, I can only navigate to the first webpage and then activate it when it pops up.

Comment: `Src` attribute specifies the address of the document to embed in the frame. In this case the address is relative so what you need is the home address to get the full address where the frame will navigate: ie.Navigate `"http://192.168.55.66:8899/Some/Intranet/Path/" & "frame.src"`.

Comment: I tried it again, but if I navigate to a frame of this "unaccessible" webpage, it doesn't work. If somehow I could say instead that I want the HTMLdocument of the activated page (so the main.html) to be reduced to the one of the src of the frame I'm interested in only it would probably work.

Comment: So you fitst login then navigate to main page and then to frame but it doesn't work? What does it mean exactly? What error you get?

Comment: I will make a new post now (which will be the following part of this one) since now the problem is not the same anymore as the topic of this post here. And I will tag you, thanks for help mate :)

Comment: Ok, you are welcome!

Comment: here is the link to the new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529581/access-to-a-webpages-frame-document-without-navigating-to-this-webpage

Answer (score 0):

Only 3 frames are on that page, the rest are inside an embedded html frame which getElementsByTagName cannot access as it is a different DOM tree.

Comment: Hmmm I see, and is there a way to access to the content of of of those 3 mainframes ?