# Running VBA code issues

Tags: html, vba

I just finished a big VBA code which is basically going on an intranet page with some weird properties (see my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529581/access-to-a-webpages-frame-document-without-navigating-to-this-webpage) for more details).

The code is pretty heavy and when I run it step by step (F8) it works but if I try to run the whole thing I get a *Object variable or With block variable not set* error.

The problem is that this error is not always popping up at the same position in the code.

What I tried to do so far :

1. Everytime I click on an element of the webpage, select a new window or any other action, I waited for the HTMLdocument of the page and the page itself to be at ready state : `Do: Loop Until doc.readyState = "complete"` and

   ```
   Sub WaitWhileBusy(ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
       While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
           DoEvents
       Wend
   End Sub
   ```

So I just spread some of those "check-points" here and there in the whole code but it didn't affect this issue at all.

2. A solution I have now, but which I don't like at all is to put the whole code in a loop while an error shows up and only exits when the end of the code was reached....

Any ideas on how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a good way to fix this issue.

I still don't fully understand why the error came up but I guess it's related to the speed of the process so what I did is that I added a Timers sub code which basically has the effect to pause the code everytime I call it and for the number of seconds I want to.

The code (which I literally copy-paste from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264416.aspx)) is the following :

Sub Timers()
Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
    PauseTime = 1    ' Set duration.
    Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
End Sub

And my issue disappeared !